# Python List Slicing Performance

Tags: python, performance, list, slice

I found that the latter was much more efficient (orders of magnitude faster). Is there any reason for this? It was done in Python 2.7.

```
block = data[y * block_length:y * (block_length + 1)] # Slow
```

vs.

```
block = [data[y * block_length + z] for z in xrange(block_length)] # Fast
```

EDIT:

Using Numpy (this could be the cause), see the code at http://pastebin.com/88KkWd79
Run it with time `python test.py a` or `time python test.py b`, as the power gets larger, function b begins to take much, much longer.

Comment: How did you confirm that the later is faster?

Comment: Used the command time.

Comment: @user2195592 Can you give us some sample data to run the tests?

Comment: [My tests](http://pastebin.com/X7UaXNKV) show the opposite. The first code block is slightly faster.

Comment: It was 2^18 data points, and was splitting the data up into multiple groups (blocks). I believe any data will do, but the fast version completed in 5 seconds, whereas the slow version took over 5 minutes before I killed it.

Comment: Note that those are not equivalent! The first list has `y` entries, the second has `block_length` entries. Did you mean `(y+1) * block_length`?

Comment: What is `data`'s type? If it's something other than an ordinary list, maybe it does something weird and slow when you index it with a slice. Numpy array, perhaps?

Comment: You used `time`, maybe you want to use [`timeit`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/timeit.html) instead?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The first one *should* be much faster. However, note that those two lists are not equivalent. The first one has `y` entries, while he second one has `block_length` entries. If `y` is very large (i.e. because you are splitting a very long list into relatively small blocks) this could account for the difference in running time.

Probably you meant this instead:

```
block = data[y * block_length : (y + 1) * block_length]
```

Comment: Wow. That was bad. :P Yes, you are correct. This is much faster, and is what I meant.